# How to have equal height columns in responsive design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I am using the matchHeight jquery plug in so that my columns have equal height. It was working great until I added two columns inside of another column.

This is the website http://heartcrossings.businesscatalyst.com/

As you can see in the *Love Stories* section the content is now going out of the main column and the background is not extending with it.

If I add more content to the "*your guided journey*" sections it adjusts the background in both columns to be the same but if I add it to the *Love stories* section this does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: inline-table;` to your box class

```
.box {
    background: url(../images/box-bkg.png) repeat;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it did not work. It adjusted the height of the box on the right but the column on the left did not adjust to match the height of the tallest box